# Calling different classes with an if statement in java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, if-statement, adventure

I am programming an TBAP (Texted base adventure program) just because. I just started it, and I am already having issues with it. What I want to do is have a main class that introduces the program, in output text. At the end of the class it asks "Where would you like to go on your adventures?" It has five options 3 of them are separate adventures of two of them are inventory classes. Right now I am stuck on the my first adventure class. I have an int variable called path. If path == 1, you go to fantasy island class go on your adventure. Is there any to call that adventure with an if statement? I made a constructor and getters and setters with my variables name and path.

Summerproject class:

```
package summerproject;


import java.util.Scanner;
import static summerproject.Fanastyisland.name;
import static summerproject.Fanastyisland.path;

public class Summerproject {
private static int path;
private static String name; 



public Summerproject (int path, String name)
{
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;


}


public String getname() {
    return name;
}




public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}




public int getPath() {
    return path;
}


    public void setPath(int path) {
    this.path = path;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to the adventure text program! You are the choosen one to save the universe");



    System.out.println("Press any key to continue...");
    try
    {
        System.in.read();
    }  
    catch(Exception e)
    {}  

    System.out.println("Welcome. You are the choose one, a legend,a becon of      hope to save the universe from the forces of evil.");
    System.out.println("Only with you skills and your great power can you destroy the evil doing world.");
    System.out.println("Please enter heros name");
    name = in.next();

    System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", lets begin our adventure!!");

    System.out.println("The world can be saved, there is hope. But in order to save the world, \n "
            + "+ you must complete 9 tasks in three diffrent places in three diffrent periods of time. The past, the present and the future.");
     System.out.println("Press any key to continue...");
    try
    {
        System.in.read();
    }  
    catch(Exception e)
    {}  

    System.out.println("The three places are the past in the year 1322 in Fantasy island");
    System.out.println("The present is the evil little town of Keene N.H.");
    System.out.println("And the future to the year 2567 in Space!"); 



    System.out.println("Where would you like to go on your adventures?");
   System.out.println(" 1). Fantasy Island");
    System.out.println(" 2). Keene");
    System.out.println(" 3). Outer space");
    System.out.println(" 4). Buy wepons or potions!");
    System.out.println(" 5). Sell wepons!"); 
    path = in.nextInt();

   if (path == 1)
    {

    }


}
}
```

here is my fantasy island class:

```
package summerproject;


import java.util.Scanner;
import static summerproject.Fanastyisland.name;
import static summerproject.Fanastyisland.path;
 public class Fanastyisland extends Summerproject {
public static String name;
    public static int path;


    public Fanastyisland (String name, int path)
    {
        super(path,name);
        name = name;
        path = path;


    }
    public String getName() {
    return name;
}




public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}




public int getPath() {
    return path;
}


    public void setPath(int Path) {
    this.path = path;
}




public static void main(String[] args) 
//this is where the fantasy island        adventure begins. 
{
   System.out.println("Welcome to fantasy island!!")



}
}
```

Like I said, I want to call the sub classes with an if statement and I don't know how to do that. If I type in one 1, I want to go to the fantasy island class. I haven't programmed the adventure yet, I will get to it once it is fixed, I just want the output for now to be "Welcome to fantasy island!" when I type 1. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Why don´t you just create a common interface with a start method which every adventure will implement, instead of making it extend `Summerproject`. then you could create a class variable with the type of the interface and just call the start method everytime.

Comment: You want to call `Fanastyisland.main(new String[0]);`  BTW you want to read lines of text at a time, and you never want to ignore exceptions unless you are really sure this is a good idea.

Comment: @KevinEsche Goahead and answer it. That's so obvious solution afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Summerproject adventure = null;
switch (path) {
  case 1:
    adventure = new FantasyIsland (...);
    break;
  case 2:
    adventure = new Keene (...);
    break;
  ...
  default:
    System.out.println ("Illegal choice(" & path & "): try again");
  }
  if (adventure != null) {
    adventure.play ();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a common interface

```
public interface Adventures{
    public void start();
}
```

Every adventure could implement this interface and override the start method

```
public class AdventureA implements Adventures {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // Do whatever you want
    }

}
```

You summerproject could simply have a class variable with the type of the interface.

```
public class Summerproject {
private static int path;
private static String name; 
private Adventure adventure;
...
}
```

Afterwards in the if statements you could just assign this adventure and call the start method.

```
if (path == 1)
{
    adventure = new AdventureA();
    adventure.start();
}
```